# Наложить текст на картинку, вывод даты

Tags: html, wordpress, css, php

Нашел в интернете решение как наложить текст на картинку. Вот только к "Подробнее" хотел бы дописать еще php код для вывода даты.

```
.imgteaser { /* общий блок */
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.imgteaser:after { /* "подробнее" */
  content: "Подробнее";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: -6px;
  padding: 5px 9px 4px 9px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.imgteaser:hover:after {content: none;}

.imgteaser figcaption {display: none;}
.imgteaser:hover figcaption { /* прозрачная область */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
right: 0px;
left: 0px;
bottom: -6px;
  padding: 5px 9px 4px 9px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
box-shadow: 0 0 15px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

-

```
<div class="miniature">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { ?> 
        <figure class="imgteaser">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >  <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail'); ?></a>  
            <figcaption>прозрачная область</figcaption>
        </figure>
    <?php } ?>      
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

Comment: Я же про "content: "Подробнее";" а не php

Comment: >>> Вот только к "Подробнее" хотел бы дописать еще php код для вывода даты.

php код для вывода даты

Comment: "Подробнее" прописан в css, туда php не запхнуть. вот я и спрашиваю альтернативу.

Comment: напридумываете всякой фигни, потом маетесь. ну и зачем дата в строке "подробнее", какой смысл она несёт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так извернуться:

```
<?php
# Условие формирования текста для блока "Подробнее" взято с потолка...
$more = "Подробнее" . ($date ? " {$date}" : "");

# Ниже подключаем инлайновые-стили, чтобы изменить значение css-свойства 'content'
?>

<style type="text/css">
.imgteaser:after { /* "подробнее" */
  content: "<?php echo $more; ?>";
}
</style>

<div class="miniature">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { ?> 
    <figure class="imgteaser">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >  <?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnail'); ?></a>  
    <figcaption>прозрачная область</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <?php } ?>      
</div>
```

Comment: Только не используйте short tags <?= ?> ибо их скоро выпилят, это раз, а второе - они могут под разной настройкой сервера не работать.

Comment: kemerov4anin, ну так и напиши свой пример без short tags

Comment: @kemerov4anin, заменил вывод.